# Check if an intent is an Activity or Service or none

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have an ArrayList of Intents, how can I check that the intent at a given position is containing an Activity, Service or nothing?

```
Intent intent = intents.get(id);
context.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

How would you check that the intent at index id could even be properly passed through `startActivityForResult`, which has an emphasis on Activity classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not a elegant solution but you can try to get class name of intent like this:

```
Intent it = new Intent(ctx, AnotherActivity.class);
it.getComponent().getClassName() // output com.package.app.MainActivity

Intent it = new Intent(ctx, JustService.class);
it.getComponent().getClassName() // output com.package.app.JustService
```

and use

```
switch (...getClassName()) {
    case 'com.package.app.JustService' {
         //todo
    }
}
```

You can use getShortClassName() method and it will output class name without default package:

```
.JustService
```

For empty intent i would check if is null.

Comment: For non Activities and Services I decided to check if Component was null

Answer (score 1):

> how can I check that the intent at a given position is containing an Activity, Service or nothing?

I am going to interpret this as "how can I see what component(s) an `Intent` could resolve to?".

If so, use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`, `queryIntentServices()`, and `queryBroadcastReceivers()`. Note that an `Intent` could be usable for none, any, or all of those.

> How would you check that the intent at index id could even be properly passed through startActivityForResult

You don't, short of finding the developers who wrote the activity and asking them "hey, will this return a result?" You could whitelist well-known result-returning action strings (e.g., `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`), but you have no means of knowing whether an arbitrary activity will return a result for a given `Intent`.

Comment: For non Activities and Services I decided to check if Component was null

Comment: @CQM: I don't know where your `Intents` are coming from, but an `Intent` does not have to have a `ComponentName` to still be valid. `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(...)` has no `ComponentName`, but still may resolve to an activity, for example.

Comment: Thanks, that was very insightful. I'll keep it in mind if my use case expands in scope and glitches are introduced.